# Very new to C# I need to read only the month in a DD/MM/YYYY style format csv file

Tags: c#

My program needs to ask the user to say a month Jan (1) Feb (2) and the program has to read the csv file and give the average of the average for each month and day of said month.
The csv file format is (date;min;avg;max).

I was expecting it to only give me the numbers for the month chosen, but with my code it is also giving me the number of for example if I say January (1) it will also give me the average of some days on Feb containing the number 1 ex(1, 10, 11... etc.).

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filepath = "temps.csv";

        try
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

            Console.WriteLine("From which month do you wish the avg is calculated? Jan (1) Feb (2)");
            string month = Console.ReadLine();

            double sum = 0;

            int countDay = 0;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(';');

                if (parts[0].Contains(month))
                {
                    sum += double.Parse(parts[2]);

                    countDay++;
                }
            }
            double average = sum / countDay;

            Console.WriteLine("The avg temp of " + mes + " is: " + average);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading file: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you parse the date using `DateTime.ParseExact` and then compare the `Month` property of the resulting `DateTime` with the entered month.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you parse `parts[0]` to a date, not just treat it as a string

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
     string[] parts = line.Split(';');
     var date = DateTime.Parse(parts[0]);
     if (date.Month == month)
     {
           sum += double.Parse(parts[2]);
           countDay++;
     }
}
```

Note the above is oversimplified - consider using `ParseExact` / `TryParseExact` and handle parsing errors appropriately.

Comment: It says, Operator "==" cannot be aplied to operators of type int and string

Comment: @VitorRocha So convert the user input to a number (`int.Parse` / `int.TryParse`)

Answer (score -1):

as I understand the proplem, you shouldn't use foreach beacause you loop for all months, instead you can get the dates using "Where in EF", or if condition.
Or, you can replace contain with "==", to get the exact month.

Comment: The ordering of the file has not been mentioned, so it's necessary to look at all lines, hence the foreach.